# HTTPHandler in VB.net for uploading files using Plupload

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, file-upload, httphandler, plupload

I have built working VB.net code that uploads multiple images to the server using Plupload. I am using an HTTPHandler (FileUpload.ashx) to do the uplading and want to add a SQL Statement that will insert each of the images File Names to my SQL Database. I have tried just adding the SQL to the Handler, but when I do I get 4 database entries for each iamge that is uploaded. I really dont understand why and need some guidance. Thanks for your time in advance.

Pertainant HANDLER code:

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

    Dim chunk As Integer = If(context.Request("chunk") IsNot Nothing, Integer.Parse(context.Request("chunk")), 0)
    Dim fileName As String = If(context.Request("name") IsNot Nothing, context.Request("name"), String.Empty)
    Dim fileUpload As HttpPostedFile = context.Request.Files(0)

    Dim uploadPath = context.Server.MapPath("Upload")
    Using fs = New FileStream(Path.Combine(uploadPath, fileName), If(chunk = 0, FileMode.Create, FileMode.Append))
        Dim buffer = New Byte(fileUpload.InputStream.Length - 1) {}
        fileUpload.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)

        fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
    End Using
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
    context.Response.Write("Success")
```

EXP: SQL insert

```
        Dim conn As SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(DBCONN)
    Dim command As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("W2_InsertPhoto " & fileName, conn)
    Dim rs As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
    conn.Open()
    rs = command.ExecuteReader()
    rs.Close()
    rs = Nothing
    conn.Close()
    conn = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using chunks then make sure that you fire your SQL aster the last chunk has been saved

For example.

```
  chunk = If(context.Request("chunk") IsNot Nothing, Integer.Parse(context.Request("chunk")), 0)
  chunks = If(context.Request("chunks") IsNot Nothing, Integer.Parse(context.Request("chunks")) - 1, 0) 


 If (chunk = chunks) Then
      'Upload is complete, Save to DB here or whatever
 end if
```

-1 is used on CHUNKS because chunks is -1 from the last chunk, if that makes sense.

To get the file name all you need to add in your handler.ashx is..

```
fileName = If(context.Request("name") IsNot Nothing, context.Request("name"), String.Empty)
```

In order to get unique fileName from Pluplaod across to your handler, you need to tell Plupload(on the client) to use unique names.

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
        runtimes: 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
        max_file_size: '20mb',
        url: '../handler.ashx',
        chunk_size: '100kb',
        unique_names: true,
        multipart_params: { imageType: $('#myDiv').attr("MyIMageType"), custom: 'This is static custom text' },
```

In your handler you call the `'name'` request again and you will have the unqie names that pluplaoder made.. also to request the data in the multipart you do as usual `request`

```
PictureType = If(context.Request("imageType") IsNot Nothing, [Enum].Parse(GetType(PictureType), context.Request("imageType")), Nothing)


Dim myCustom as String = If(context.Request("custom") IsNot Nothing, context.Request("custom"))
```

**In response to your SQL you need to encapsulate the file name withing `'` otherwise spaces and special characters will break the SQLCommand, because SQL will think its another variable or command instead of treating it purely as a string. This is also a common problem for SQL Injection.. Allowing hackers to inject code because of code like this.**

Comment: Thanks for the reply ppumpkin. I can use your code and succesfully insert a one record per file (instead of multple inserts like before) "so that is good"... BUT I still cant insert a unique name for each of the files using the "FileName" value.

I guess I am confused how I am suppose to get the unique filename for each file I upload if I am doing the insert "after" the last file (if chunks -1) is uploaded.

Comment: @Jason I added some more examples. I also use jQuery `$` to get some data into mulitpart. Use fiddler to catch the data being sent over and debug your handler, look inside `context.current.request.forms` for the paramaters. Also please consider upvoting or accepting my anser. Thanks

Comment: Point taken on the sql code, it was done quick and dirty just for this post. The iamges I am testing with dont have any special characters or spaces. Do you have any further suggestions for the issue I am having?

Sorry for posting new question, I couldnt figure out how to edit my question and post new "code"

Comment: without actual code then I cannot really say. It is down to debugging now and supplying the actual code does help allot

Comment: ppumkin, you are winderful. I have been out of town and working on other projects. I just got back on this and the light went on for me. I got it to work, all thanks to you. I am very grateful!!!

Comment: no problem- as an added bonus you could also upvote me aswell as accept answers. Thanks you :-]

Answer (score 1):

ppumpkin, I dont think I am explaining myself well. Sorry for what I am sure is lamens terms, I am new to plupload and handlers all at the same time.

I am using unique naming as "false" because I need to retain the original name of each file. I am currently naming the filenames correctly on upload to server, but for my SQL insert I need those same names inserted. If I try and use the FileName that I declared (context.Request("name")) as a value in my SQL Statement I immediately get an error and no inserted value. If I use a static value for filename just to test, it inserts just fine, but of course its the same name for each file I upload.

Including your updates, this what I currently have for my handler and clients script.

Handler:

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

    Dim chunk As Integer = If(context.Request("chunk") IsNot Nothing, Integer.Parse(context.Request("chunk")), 0)
    Dim chunks As Integer = If(context.Request("chunks") IsNot Nothing, Integer.Parse(context.Request("chunks")) - 1, 0)
    Dim fileName As String = If(context.Request("name") IsNot Nothing, context.Request("name"), String.Empty)

    If (chunk = chunks) Then
        Dim conn As SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(mdata.DBCONN)
        Dim command As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("W2_InsertPhoto 12345," & **fileName**, conn)
        Dim rs As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
        conn.Open()
        rs = command.ExecuteReader()
        rs.Close()
        rs = Nothing
        conn.Close()
        conn = Nothing
    End If

    Dim fileUpload As HttpPostedFile = context.Request.Files(0)

    Dim uploadPath = context.Server.MapPath("Upload")
    Using fs = New FileStream(Path.Combine(uploadPath, fileName), If(chunk = 0, FileMode.Create, FileMode.Append))
        Dim buffer = New Byte(fileUpload.InputStream.Length - 1) {}
        fileUpload.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
    End Using
End Sub
```

My client Script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Convert divs to queue widgets when the DOM is ready
    $(function () {
        $("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
            // General settings,silverlight,browserplus,html5gears,
            runtimes: 'flash',
            url: 'FileUpload.ashx',
            max_file_size: '10mb',
            chunk_size: '1mb',
            unique_names: false,

            // Specify what files to browse for
            filters: [{ title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,jpeg,gif,png,bmp"}],
            // Flash settings
            flash_swf_url: 'assets/resources/plupload.flash.swf',


            // Silverlight settings
            silverlight_xap_url: 'assets/resources/plupload.silverlight.xap',

            init: {
                FileUploaded: function (up, file, info) {
                }
            }
        });

        // Client side form validation
        $('form').submit(function (e) {
            var uploader = $('#uploader').pluploadQueue();

            // Validate number of uploaded files
            if (uploader.total.uploaded == 0) {
                // Files in queue upload them first
                if (uploader.files.length > 0) {
                    // When all files are uploaded submit form
                    uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function () {
                        if (uploader.total.uploaded == uploader.files.length)
                            $('form').submit();
                    });
                    uploader.start();
                } else
                    alert('You must at least upload one file.');

                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
        //tweak to reset the interface for new file upload
        $('#btnReset').click(function () {
            var uploader = $('#uploader').pluploadQueue();

            //clear files object
            uploader.files.length = 0;

            $('div.plupload_buttons').css('display', 'block');
            $('span.plupload_upload_status').html(''); 
            $('span.plupload_upload_status').css('display', 'none');
            $('a.plupload_start').addClass('plupload_disabled');
            //resetting the flash container css property
            $('.flash').css({
                position: 'absolute', top: '292px',
                background: 'none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent',
                width: '77px',
                height: '22px',
                left: '16px'
            });
            //clear the upload list
            $('#uploader_filelist li').each(function (idx, val) {
                $(val).remove();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```